# Converting Python nested loop to PHP nested loop

Tags: python, php, for-loop

I have created the following nested for loop in python - the idea is to take a int value for hours e.g 6 and then create an array of values from 1-6

```
hours = 6
hoursArray = [6]
convertHours = [] #Creating empty list



for i in hoursArray:
    for j in range(i-1): #This will iterate till the value in list - 1
        convertHours.append(j+1) #Appending values in new list
        hoursList = convertHours + hoursArray
    print(hoursList) #adding both the lists
```

output
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Here is my attempt with php - I'm confused about the inner loop and how to do "for j in range(i-1)" in php also in php i should be getting the max value of the array into the range of the outer loop `for($i = 0; $i <= $hoursArray-1; $i++)`  - again i'm not sure how to do this so i put in the int value `$hours` to test it.

```
<?php
$hours = 6;
$hoursArray = [$hours];
$convertHours =[];

for($i = 0; $i <= $hours-1; $i++) {

     for($j = 0; $j <= $i-1; $j++) {
      $convertHours = [$j+1];
      $hoursList = array_merge($convertHours, $hoursArray);

   }

 }
var_dump($hoursList);
print_r($hoursList);

?>
```

Output
array(2) {
[0]=>
int(5)
[1]=>
int(6)
}
Array
(
[0] => 5
[1] => 6
)

Any help appreciated!!

Update: This solves the issue (although its not a nested loop)

```
<?php
$hours = 6;
$convertHours =[];
for($i = 0; $i <= $hours-1; $i++) {
  $convertHours[] = $i+1;
}
var_dump($convertHours);

?>
```

OUPTPUT = array(6) {
[0]=>
int(1)
[1]=>
int(2)
[2]=>
int(3)
[3]=>
int(4)
[4]=>
int(5)
[5]=>
int(6)
}

Comment: In python your first `for` iterate over  `hoursArray` (so only once) but in php you iterate over `i < 5`, is this a mistake by any chance ?

Comment: Yes the python iteration should take the value 5 as the loop goes 1-5 then appends 6 to the final merged list

Comment: why'd you even consider converting python to php?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line of `$convertHours = [$j+1];`. This way you overwrite the value that was in $convertHours before. You have to write `$convertHours[] = $j+1;`
This way there will be a new value appended to the array. Alternatevly you can also use `array_push($convertHours, $j+1)`

Comment: Thanks this helped but the output of the php array is not the same as the python output:
I changed $convertHours = [$j+1]; to $convertHours[] = $j+1; The output is now

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 3
    [13] => 4
    [14] => 5
    [15] => 6
)

Answer (score 1):

`array_merge` merges the 2 arrays based on their `key`

> ```
> $convertHours = [$j+1];
> ```

Is equivalent to:

> ```
> $convertHours = [0 => $j+1];
> ```

So when you merge them they all have the same `key` but differents `values`.

You should do something like that I think:

> ```
> for($j = 0; $j <= $i-1; $j++) {
>   $hoursArray[] = $j+1; 
> }
> ```

This append to your `array` the values `$j+1` then ultimately you could use `sort` to sort your array